# How to populate Firebase Database data in TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

In my app the first TableView shows ads in a specific subcategory and the user can change between subcategories and the tableview reloads and shows the relevant content. They click on a cell and are taken to a Viewcontroller which displays more detailed information. The ads in the tableview are listed in order of distance from the user.

I have gotten this to work by having a loading screen when the app is opened where I download the whole database, calculate the distance from the user (for each branch then finding the closest one and using those coordinates), append everything to an array ["Ad code", "distance in km"] -> ["A1-2-3", 28] then I use this to populate cells in the tableview and get the number of cells by counting the array. I don't really like this solution as if I update the database while the is open the app will crash, sometimes the loading screen exits before the downloading sorting has finished causing the tableview to crash. I tried to download the data then sort it but it crashing (it tried to start sorting the array before it was populated) so I moved the sorting code into the "Firebase Block".

My question is Is there a better way do this than downloading the entire database when the app is opened? As when the database grows the download etc will increase.

Format -> "A0-1-2" - "A0" is the category (1, 2, 3 etc), 1 is the subcategory and "2" is the advert number.

My JSON tree looks like this

```
"Adverts" : {
    "A0" : {
      "A0-0" : {
        "A0-0-0" : {
          "Branches" : [ {
            "Branch Name" : "Florida Road",
            "Latitude" : 1234,
            "Longitude" : 1234
          } ],
          "Images" : {
            "0" : "link",
            "1" : "link",
            "2" : "link",
            "Thumbnail" : "link"
          },
          "Info" : {
            "Name" : "The Barn Owl",
            "Price" : 28.98
          },
          "Social Media" : {
            "Facebook" : "link",
            "Instagram" : "Link",
            "Twitter" : "link",
            "Website" : "link"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'll try to give you a hand here because the question is very vague so pleased edit before it's closed. First, we don't really know what's being asked - are you asking about the structure or some code (which was not included) or something else? Second statements like *a bit glitchy* and *Is this the correct way to do it* are totally subjective - are you asking for help with the glitchy code? If so, what's glitchy about it? Or what's not correct about your current use case? Lastly, SO is for coding specific questions, and not really about overall design. Please update your question.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question @Jay

Answer (score 0):

This is a very difficult question to answer accurately because of the number of variables involved;

How big is your database?
How often will you need to perform this calculation - is it event driven?
What's your budget
What's the overall use case.

However, it's asked quite frequently so let me add a few datapoints.

1. Database Size Matters:
   If you have 100 users you're calculating distance on then it's no big deal to download that when the app opens and perform your distance calculation. However, if you have 100,000 users, well, if you download the entire database, it will not only cause a poor experience for the user while it does that download and calculation, you could also overwhelm the device and cause it to crash. It can also affect the total cost
2. Frequency matters:
   How often you hit the database also like #1 affects the user experience as well as impacting the total cost
3. How fat is your wallet:
   It costs money to pull down data and the size and frequency affect that
4. What's the overall implementation and use case:
   There's not enough info in the question to adequately evaluate this so the question itself probably needs clarification.

There are a number approaches, but here's two

- Do as you are doing; download the data, perform the calculations. If it's a small amount of data, probably the best choice. If not, see the next bullet point
- Let the Firebase server do the heavy lifting and only present data to your app that it's interested in. e.g. why download data from someone that's 200 miles away when you're only interested in someone 2 miles away.

So the thought process here is to 'encode' your coordinates that are stored in firebase so they (distance wise) can have a conceptual query like this

```
let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "distance").queryStarting(atValue: 0).queryEnding(atValue: 2)
```

So... you have some options there. One is to craft your own using [geohashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash)

the other is to use a pre-built library that does the work for you. Check out [GeoFire](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/geofire-objc/). With GeoFire, to get all the users within a 2 mile radius, here's the query

```
var circleQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(center, withRadius: 2)
```

You can have it present events as users goes into or out of that radius or limit the number of results.